# How can we improve the traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion, advertising

As the community is growing really fast, it's time we do some growth hacking for improving the number of visits(traffic) and dedicated users on the site. So, any views on how to go about it?

Are there any reddit sites where we can cross-post the questions?

PS: This site is an excellent example of "Vote early, vote often" principle; which has been the trait of very few succesful sites. Kudos! Keep at it.

Answer (score 4):

We should definitely work on reaching out for more traffic and new users.

The first possibilities that come to mind are:

- reddit, which you suggested – there are a whole lot of great subs to post in that could bring tons of new users (r/buildapc, r/hardware, and r/techsupport to name a few)
- creating some more community ads for other SE sites – could help just a little but is also a very slow process

We're sitting at a steady 100 visits per day right now, but we've had a massive increase in page views and small increases in visits. Advertising on reddit would help with page views and would also provide a little jump in new users.

Over the next week or two we will absolutely be looking into all of this.

Comment: Regarding the community ads, do we have an updated list of sites where we have active ads? The most recent I see is [here](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/219/community-promotion-ads-lets-advertise-this-site). Is that still accurate?

Comment: As far as I know, it is, unless someone posted an ad somewhere and didn't tell anyone.

Comment: I'm not suggesting running a full paid for ad, but the reddit advertisement platform has subreddits broken into Interest Groups. There is a Technology Interest group: https://reddit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205803423-Interest-Groups-